# VueJS Axios, how to get data from array

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, axios

I'm trying to use the data from [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAkhs.png) JSON file. I can see using Vue Devtools that I've got the data, but I am unsure how to access it.

I'm storing the data like this:

```
let app = new Vue({
      el: "#app",
      data: {
        n_btc: {}
    }
```

and then trying to access it with `{{n_btc.Data.title}}`

I also tried `{{n_btc.Data[0].title}}`(as I recognised it as an array), but this didn't work either.

What would be the correct way to access `title`?

Comment: Can you show the code for your axios call? Are there any errors in devtools console? Also, value of `n_btc.Data[0].title` wouldn't be set until ajax finishes, so you need to take that into consideration when you render data.

Comment: Is n_btc storing the contents of that entire json file? If so it will need be accessed like this: `n_btc.n_btc.Data[0].title`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding you seems new to `Vue`

I guess you try to access the data some where indie mounted or after your  `axios` call , so

after your data returned from a call

you should assigned like that

```
this.n_btc = YOUR_RESPONSE.n_btc
```

and later on you access by `this.n_btc.Data[0].title`

```
console.log(this.n_btc.Data[0].title)
```